# Emulating Synesthesia: How to change the colour of words based on the first letter in a system-wide manner?

Tags: linux, colors, fonts

I want to try to understand how [Daniel Tammet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Tammet), an autistic synesthetic savant, sees words, at least in the aspect of them having colour. To this aim, I want to colour every word appearing on the screen with some colour, which is to be determined by the first letter of the word. For example, this should apply to the UI, to PDFs, to the Terminal, and so on.

**Question:** Is it possible to make your Linux distribution paint every word on the screen with a specific colour based on the first letter? How about colouring numbers?

Here's an example of the behaviour I'm aiming for:

> ask, answer, allow, at, amount are coloured green;
>
> red, rave, round, river, rent are coloured red;
>
> 4 is coloured blue, 5 is coloured yellow, and 6 is coloured green.

Comment: I hope this question is on-topic, even though it seems to be somewhat unusual. In case it is actually off-topic, I apologize. If so, would it be appropriate for some other StackExchange site?

Comment: I guess that being about Linux your question is on-topic. The problem lies on the fact that Linux is a collection of software, not a monolitic system. Maybe you can change a specific software, but not system-wide. For example: firefox is it's own software, that relies on specific engines of rendering, not related to "Linux" as OS.